# SQL query to find empty values with complex condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have primary table (`table1` - contains customer main information) that is related to another table (`table2` - contains customer contact information) and common value is `ID`.

In primary table the `ID` value gives me 1 row, another table may gives me more rows, depending on how many contact types the customer has, for example:

- main_phone (this row always exists)
- home_phone
- work_phone
- mobile etc.

What I am trying to achieve:

First I want to check mobile value, if row is missing or there is no mobile value, but row exists then I want to check `main_phone` value.

But if there is `mobile` value then I don't want to check the `main_phone` value.
If `main_phone` value also missing then I want these records.

Currently I have query:

```
Select customer 
From table1 t1 
Join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id
Where t2.type in (main_phone, mobile)
  And t2.type_values in ('',null,'-')
```

but the problem is, if customers has mobile number and missing phone number, these client records also show up in the result.

Comment: show a proper data sample and the expected  result

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Are you trying to find customers without mobile or main_phone numbers?

Answer (score 0):

this might get you close..

```
SELECT  customer
FROM    table1 t1 
WHERE   NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT  1
    FROM    table2 t2 
    WHERE   t1.id = t2.id
            AND t2.type in (main_phone, mobile)
            and ISNULL(t2.type_value,'') NOT IN ('','-')
)
```

if it finds a value in the NOT EXISTS query it will be excluded

Answer (score 0):

You have to be careful and treat null as a special value. The two queries below will return different results.

```
Select COUNT(*) from table1 t1 
join table2 t2 on t1.id=t2.id
where t2.type in (main_phone, mobile)
and t2.type_values in ('',null,'-')

Select COUNT(*) from table1 t1 
join table2 t2 on t1.id=t2.id
where t2.type in (main_phone, mobile)
and (t2.type_values IS NULL) OR(t2.type_values in ('','-'))
```

You should get in the habit of testing for null using a null comparison such as X IS NULL, NOT X IS NULL, ISNULL() or COALESCE().

Answer (score 0):

did you want something like this?

```
SELECT 
    customer 
FROM 
    table1 t1 JOIN
    (SELECT 
        id 
    FROM 
        table1 t1 JOIN 
        table2 t2 ON 
        t1.id=t2.id
    WHERE 
        t2.TYPE = mobile AND 
        (t2.type_values IS NULL OR
        t2.type_values IN ('','-') ))  missing_mobile ON
    t1.id = missing_mobile.id
WHERE   
        t2.TYPE = main_phone AND 
        (t2.type_values IS NULL OR
        t2.type_values IN ('','-') )
```